# Changing shape's coords on keypress

Tags: javascript, canvas, keypress

I have a `<canvas/>`, and a shape rendering on it. I am trying to change the shape's coordinates on keypress, but am having no luck.

Here's my source:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 35;

var xPos = 0;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(xPos, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke(); 

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 100) {
        xPos++;
    }
});
```

Another issue I am having is figuring out what keys are what number? Is there a chart somewhere? I saw two conflicting values on different sites.

Comment: I'll just make a guess that the reason for ___two conflicting values on different sites___ is related to this interesting fact from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):
_Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/htmlcss/move-objects-around-the-canvas-using-the-keyboard-and-jquery/ goes into great detail using jQuery to reference a Canvas object and then manipulate that object.

It also examines how to adjust the position of that Canvas object in response to keystrokes entered by the user.

Hope that helps.